# How to decode json object for database in cakephp 3.0

Tags: php, json, cakephp

I am trying to do a new database entry off of a http post request in cakephp 3. In cakephp 3 they are now using entities to manipulate the data. I have a rest api that uses json. I want to take that json data and put it in my database, here is what I am doing -

```
    public function add() {
    $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
    $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
    $array = $user->toArray();
    $this->Users->save($user);}
```

My json data that is being sent in http post -

**{"userID":60,"firstname":"Sherbert60","lastname":"Dafflemore60","profilepic":"nada"}**

The error I receive -

**Error: Call to a member function errors() on array 
File /var/app/current/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/Table.php 
Line: 1356**

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Thanks

**EDIT** -

Read in the docs that cakephp will automatically handle it if it is json, so I changed my code to -

```
    $user = $this->Users->newEntity($this->request->data);
    if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
        $message = 'Saved';
    } else {
        $message = 'Error';
    }
```

Now I get a 200 response with no entry into database. I can query the database with no problems.

Comment: No, because you didn't post the line that's throwing the error. Post whatever's on line 1356.

Comment: @ Adelphia if ($entity->errors()) {
            return false;
        }

Comment: Looks like `$entity` is an array, not an object.

Comment: You'll have to figure out why you were expecting an object and got an array, you haven't given enough code for us to figure that one out, but generally if you want to insert a JSON object to a database, you want to encode it, not decode. Just use `json_decode()`. When you pull the object back out of the datatbase, you can turn it back into an object (or an array) with `json_encode()`

Comment: considering what you said I changed the code to -         $user = $this->Users->newEntity($this->request->data);
        if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
            $message = 'Saved';
        } else {
            $message = 'Error';
        }  Now I get a 200 response but nothing is added to the database

Comment: I got that last comment a little backwards but you get where i'm going with it.. good luck

Comment: If you could post a little more code I'd be happy to help you, but I cant troubleshoot what I can't see.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I really have no more code to show. The controller class uses only this action and the user's table is - <?php
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;


class UsersTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->primaryKey('user_id');
    }
}

?>